# How do I perform Web Scraping in Android?

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, htmlunit

I want to scrape my website and then use the data from the website to populate elements in my app, my website has login pages and certain pages only open after the login has been done.

I started working with HtmlUnit as it is a headless browser and completed the custom api in a java IDE, later i tried to use the jar i generated from the java IDE and found that there are incompatibility issues with HtmlUnit and Android.

Can anyone propose a solution to this problem?

**Edit :**
Since no one actually answered this question I am currently going with a work around using android's native WebView, settings its Visibility to invisible and then using javascript interfacing to a Java object, I can inject JS code to scrape any data.

Comment: If you're scraping HTML from your own website to use the data in your own app, you're doing it incomprehensibly wrong.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to scrape your own website? It would be much better to have your app connect to your server, via a special API if necessary, and pull information from there.

Comment: I just want to do it that way, I like the idea of my app and website being two different entities and not accessing the internals of my website, so is there any solution ?

Comment: see my answer. I hope it will help you

Comment: I think it is a great idea because you can use google sites to create a free web page and have your app scrape that page for what to display, then no server needed, or server cost. This process also allows you to change content across all installed apps instantly! No upgrading to newer version of app to get new data.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library for such purpose. Very handy and easy to use.
Start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835555/5275639) and follow documents and other examples.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Zeeshan, i am trying to use jsoup for my purpose, but the problem is in a login page there can be many hidden variables and there can be javascript methods instead of direct submits , the code won't be straight forward as something like getPage().getForms[0].click();

Answer (score 4):

- Either you **[contribute to HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)** to produce a version of **HtmlUnit** not using ***[the missing dependencies from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885422/how-to-use-htmlunit-with-my-android-project)***.
- Or you can use an alternative method like this **[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925061/how-to-get-all-cookies-or-cookies-url-from-android-webkit-cookiemanager/#14927665)**, as this seems to be the path someone else go before you.

If a real ***headless*** browser able to manage any recent web features, would exist, it would mean a team would have developed it and then invest much effort in it (in supporting existing and coming features) consistently.

Apart from Opera, Chrome, IE, and Firefox browsers, there is no such team.
I would point out Chromium (CEF) as the most open and actively supported cross language wise. Try [Cef for java](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef)

Comment: I have read all those posts before but at the end all of them say its(htmlunit) is incompatible with android, basically i want a headless browser which can be programmed to surf like a real human would.

Comment: Any requests to find a recommended tool/technology etc... is off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: hey Fab! i am very much sure I didn't ask someone to name a technology or api, i want a solution to webscraping from a android app which has user friendly methods like they have in HtmlUnit since htmlunit is not compatible with android, can you think of some solution?