# Parsing source video file links from url or page?

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, web

I want to know whether i can parse the source link of an video from a site.
I've seen apps doing same.
for example how can i parse video links from the site 
http://www.hotstar.com/movies/2-states/1000034502/watch
i don't know how  the scrapping works but any direction to the work may help.

The app i found doing same is called Videoder.

here is the screenshot i captured 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDOM.png)

Comment: U need to use web scraping to get the source link.

Comment: @AnubhavGupta Any directions would be great sir. Hints if you can give. ThankYou.

Comment: Use https://jsoup.org/ this library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469737/how-do-i-perform-web-scraping-in-android

Comment: Also follow the above stack overflow link

Comment: @AnubhavGupta Thanks for the info. I used try.jsoup,org but didn't found any download links related to the video. Please assist me. The link is same which is posted in the main question i want to extract the video download link for the same link which i mentioned.