# importing HtmlUnit to Android project

Tags: java, android, dependencies, htmlunit

I downloaded the htmlunit-2.xx-OSGi.jar from htmlunit sourceforge page. Moved that jar into my /lib folder and when I import these I get error.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient; 
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
```

ERROR:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What am I doing wrong or how can I use this library?

Comment: I bet on dex's methods limit ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlUnit` doesn't work with android, because of JVM and DVM. You can also try using `Selenium`, which is very similar in working to `HtmlUnit`, reference [for selenium](http://selendroid.io).

Refer [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15868370/2414073)